# Rapids on colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, rapids, cudf

I have always used following commands to install Rapids on Colab (from https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rY7Ln6rEE1pOlfSHCYOVaqt8OvDO35J0#forceEdit=true&offline=true&sandboxMode=true)

```
!git clone https://github.com/rapidsai/rapidsai-csp-utils.git
!python rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/env-check.py

!bash rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/update_gcc.sh
import os
os._exit(00)

import condacolab
condacolab.install()

import condacolab
condacolab.check()

# Installing RAPIDS is now 'python rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/install_rapids.py <release> <packages>'
# The <release> options are 'stable' and 'nightly'.  Leaving it blank or adding any other words will default to stable.
!python rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/install_rapids.py stable
import os
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so'
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice/'
os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] = '/usr/local'
```

it always worked, but lately I get

*An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai/linux-64/ucx-1.11.2 gef2bbcf-cuda11.2_0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: 00:00.358595*

I have retried several times but it doesnt work, how can I solve it?

Comment: Likely related to a [Cloudflare outage impacting Conda](https://twitter.com/condaproject/status/1549778710219444225)

Comment: that was it apparently